# Can an obligatory act be missed in favour of another?

Tags: fiqh, fard

Is there any thing as "precedence" when we perform obligatory acts? Here, "precedence" means that one of acts that is lower in status can be skipped in favor of an act higher in status in a situation when both of them cannot be performed, although both of them is obligatory.

For example, we know that reciting Surah Fatiha in a rak'ah is obligatory. Now, while praying in congregation, it is obligatory to follow the Imam. But, I have seen recently after moving to a new country, that sometimes the followers behind the Imam who haven't finished reciting the Surah Fatihah, continue reciting it although Imam has gone to Ruku'. Sometimes, even when the Imam has gone to Sujud, they don't follow until they have finished reciting. After which they go through the "pending" prostrations and catch up with the Imam. Clearly, they have given "precedence" to reciting Surah Fatihah over following the Imam. Is there any basis for this?

Comment: @Medi1Saif I added more context. Is it alright now?

Comment: I can't say more than the example has a clear answer. In case of non-obligatory acts there is also a kind of "order" to follow. As for obligatory acts I can only assume or conclude a possible answer based on the few examples I actually know of. Maybe somebody else has more knowledge.

Comment: Your example is problematic as wudu is a precondition of prayer and prayer is invalid without it. Obligatory acts can not be skipped, if delayed they need to be made up.

Comment: @UmH I made a major edit to my scenario